# VisualStudio 2010 plugin settings constantly get reset

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I have VS2010 Ultimate on my dev machine, along with ReSharper, VSCommands2010 and few others.

settings for vs2010, resharper, and other plugins get reset every once in a while - so i have to go in and set them up again, then restart VS for new settings to kick in.

examples of settings i'm talking about:

```
*resharper intellisense ingreation
*resharper highlite current line
*resharper participation in customer program (systray icon)
*VSCommands2010 regex solution name
*etc.
```

is it possible to make VS remember all those settings once and forever.

Comment: This would be a better fit on SO and I voted to migrate.  Good rule of thumb is that if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If your question has you in front of a white board it belongs on Programmers.

Comment: @Walter good to know thanks, I don't mind if it's migrated

Comment: I've never had my settings resetted

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? It is possible that one of them is misbehaving.

Comment: @Michael - unlikely, it was doing the same when I had just reSharper

Answer (score 1):

A coworker has the same problem but I do not. The difference between our setups is that I store my VS.NET settings locally and he stores them on his network redirected folder over the wire.

In general I've found that VS.NET doesn't really like having its settings stored on some other machine and so I've never let it do that. I store them in my D:[Projects][VS.NET][Settings] folder and I use the square brackets so when I order the folder list alphabetically, those babies are at the top.